# WAS Starting applications with scripting, Which bat or sh file will be called

Tags: websphere

Start the application:
The following example invokes the startApplication operation on the MBean, providing the application name that you want to start.
Using Jacl:
$AdminControl invoke $appManager startApplication myApplication
Using Jython:
AdminControl.invoke(appManager, 'startApplication', 'myApplication')

I wanna know which bat or which sh file will get invoked as a result of the above script which is invoked implicitly by WAS Integrated Solution Console when anyone try to:

1. Navigate to http : // IP:PORT /ibm/console/login.do
2. Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications
3. Highlight/Checkbox/Select Any Enterprise Application fro the list of Enterprise Applications listed.
4. Press Stop/Start

I was expecting this action to invoke %WAS_HOME%\profiles\AppSrv01\bin\startServer.bat

But I couldn't find the echo messages I put in that file in any log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all implementation details, but the admin console doesn't actually use any scripts.  Instead, it uses JMX directly to invoke the same MBean ApplicationManager start/stopApplication operation that the Jacl snippet does.

Comment: Ok, so at the end will be any WAS' bat or sh files get invoked as a result of the stop/start application operations or not?

Comment: As I said, the admin console doesn't actually use any scripts.